# Sortable Blazor DataGrid using DataTable

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am trying to use a Blazor DataGrid from a component library like MudBlazor, QuickGrid, Radzen, etc. The problem I've run into is that I need a DataGrid to work with a DataTable since the results in my table will be various Sql query results and I don't have a model I can map to TItem or column properties.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675992/blazor-datagrid-using-datatable) trying to do the same thing. I'll paste the code solution from this post below. There's only one answer and someone provides an example of how to accomplish this in QuickGrid. I can get this to work, but I can't get the sorting to work.

Does anyone know how I can make the sorting work or get this working in MudBlazor? Thanks!

```
@using System.Data
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
@inject DataService DataService

@if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    <div style="height:25em; overflow:scroll">
        <QuickGrid TGridItem="DataRow" ItemsProvider="provider" Virtualize="true" ItemSize="35">
            @foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c[column.ColumnName])" Sortable="true">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        @column.ColumnName
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </PropertyColumn>
            }
        </QuickGrid>
    </div>
}

@code
{
    DataTable table = new();
    //IQueryable<DataRow> = table.AsQueryable();
    GridItemsProvider<DataRow>? provider;

    void Load(int setNum)
    {
        table = DataService.GetDataTable(setNum);   // some testdata
        var rows = table.AsEnumerable().ToList(); 
        var providerResult = GridItemsProviderResult
            .From<DataRow>(rows, rows.Count);
        provider = req => ValueTask.FromResult(providerResult);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Load(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice is not to use 3rd party.  Blazor is so good at putting pieces together that it will probably be easier just to make your own.  You can add new features if/when you need them.

Comment: Sorting with `Quickgrid` is easy. When using the delegate for the `ItemsProvider` the request only specifies the columns and direction of the sort it does not do the sort for you. The example you provide only sets the provider once. You need to write you own implementation of the delegate and react to the sort parameters provided.

Answer (score 0):

This does not use a `DataTable` but it does show how to wire up to the delegate to respond to QuickGrids sort state.

This code generates a query string for an ODATA endpoint enabling virtualization for **large** datasets

```cs
<QuickGrid ItemsProvider=itemsProvider
           TGridItem="Tenant"
           Class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm table-hover"
           Virtualize=true>
...
```

```cs
...
GridItemsProvider<Tenant> itemsProvider => GetTenants;

private async ValueTask<GridItemsProviderResult<Tenant>> 
    GetTenants(GridItemsProviderRequest<Tenant> request)
{
    var sortColumns = request.GetSortByProperties();
    string queryString = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in sortColumns)
    {
        var name = item.PropertyName;
        var direction = item.Direction switch
        {
            SortDirection.Descending => "desc",
            _ => "asc"
        };

        queryString += $"{name} {direction}";
    }

    if (queryString != string.Empty)
    {
        queryString = "$orderby=" + queryString;
    }

    ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<Tenant>> r
        = await this.apiBroker.GetTenantsAsync(request.StartIndex, request.Count ?? 200, queryString, request.CancellationToken)!;

    GridItemsProviderResult<Tenant> result = new()
    {
        Items = r.Items.Select(a => a.Item).ToList(),
        TotalItemCount = r.TotalItemsCount
    };

    return result;
}
```

```cs
public partial class ApiBroker : IApiBroker
{
...
    public async ValueTask<ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<Tenant>>> GetTenantsAsync(
        int startIndex,
        int count,
        string queryString,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await GetItemsAsync<Tenant>(
            endpoint: "Tenants",
            startIndex: startIndex,
            count: count,
            queryString: queryString,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    private async ValueTask<ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<TItem>>> GetItemsAsync<TItem>(
        string endpoint,
        int startIndex,
        int count,
        string queryString,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = $"odata/{endpoint}?{queryString}&$skip={startIndex}&$top={count}&$count=true";

        OdataResponce<TItem> response = await this.HttpClient.GetContentAsync<OdataResponce<TItem>>(relativeUrl: query, cancellationToken);

        var contextItems = response.Items.Select((item, index) => new ItemContextResult<TItem>(item, index + startIndex)).ToList();

        return new ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<TItem>>(contextItems, totalItemsCount: response.TotalItemsCount);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a **MudBlazor** **DataGrid**.  What I did for this was to wire up the Grid to a ResultDataRow class that I created. I also extracted and stored the column info separately.

Both the column info and the row data I have moving through a middle layer that deals with handling sql, so my client side knows nothing about the sql and doesn't actually work directly with the DataSet.  *But the ADO.Net collections as I recall also threw errors, so I would move the data into simpler classes like this.*

```
public class ResultDataRow
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<DateTime> DateValues { get; set; } = new List<DateTime>();
}

public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}
```

Then I used this such as:

```
<MudDataGrid T="ResultDataRow" ServerData="LoadGridData" @ref="dataGrid" DragDropColumnReordering="true" FixedHeader="true" Hideable="true" ShowMenuIcon="true" HeaderClass="grid-header" ColumnsPanelReordering="true" >
    <Columns>
    @{
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.Count - 1; i++ )
        {
            var colIndex = i;
            var column = columns[i];

            <PropertyColumn Property="@(r => r.Values[colIndex])" Title="@(column.Display)" Comparer="@(new MudBlazor.Utilities.NaturalComparer())" Filterable="true">
                <CellTemplate>
                    @context.Item.Values[colIndex].ToString()
                </CellTemplate>                    
             </PropertyColumn>
         }
     }
     </Columns>
         <PagerContent>
             <MudDataGridPager T="ResultDataRow" PageSizeOptions="@(new int[] {10,25,50,100})" />
         </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

You'll need to also acquire your data:

```
private async Task<GridData<ResultDataRow>> LoadGridData(GridState<ResultDataRow> state)
{
    var items = new List<ResultDataRow>();
    // ...
    var totalItems = ...

    GridData<ResultDataRow> data = new()
    {
        Items = items.AsEnumerable(),
        TotalItems = totalItems 
    }; 

    return data;
}
```

I tried to simplify this example to remove some of the complexity, as my actual implementation isn't short. But what I want you to focus on is the **PropertyColumn** tag and it's **Property parameter** usage, as that's what I'm attempting to show when it comes to getting dynamic data onto a grid.  **The main idea is to populate a different class holding all the values, to get around the issues the ADO.Net collections run into if you tried to use them directly.** (They will throw errors.)

But then, if you want to **sort** the grid, use the **SetSortAsync** method of the data grid reference.

```
@code {
    private List<Column> columns;
    private MudDataGrid<ResultDataRow>? dataGrid;
    //...
  dataGrid!.SetSortAsync(columns[firstRunSortColumnIndex].Display, SortDirection.Descending, x => { return x.DateValues[firstRunSortColumnIndex]; }, new MudBlazor.Utilities.NaturalComparer());
```

In this case I was looking for specific columns, and choosing a default sort based on the first I found of the expected possibilities.